# How convert date in SQL with respect to system culture?

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, date-conversion, string-to-datetime

Currently am using below mentioned code

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, "16-05-2015 21:27:25.280",105)
```

Using this its working in my system culture and one of our client in UK.
But facing issue in our US client.

Error message:

> The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

So there any way to convert the string to `DATETIME` depends on system culture like in .net.

Thanks in advance

Thejus T V

Answer (score 2):

The various settings (language, date format) only influence how the `DateTime` is shown to you in SQL Server Management Studio - or how it is parsed when you attempt to convert a string to a `DateTime`.

There are many formats supported by SQL Server - see the [MSDN Books Online on `CAST` and `CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). Most of those formats are **dependent** on what settings you have - therefore, these settings might work some times - and sometimes not.

The way to solve this is to use the (slightly adapted) **ISO-8601 date format** that is supported by SQL Server - this format works **always** - regardless of your SQL Server language and dateformat settings.

The [ISO-8601 format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878.aspx) is supported by SQL Server comes in two flavors:

- `YYYYMMDD` for just dates (no time portion); note here: **no dashes!**, that's very important! `YYYY-MM-DD` is **NOT** independent of the dateformat settings in your SQL Server and will **NOT** work in all situations!

or:

- `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS` for dates and times - note here: this format *has* dashes (but they *can* be omitted), and a fixed `T` as delimiter between the date and time portion of your `DATETIME`.

This is valid for SQL Server 2000 and newer.

If you use SQL Server 2008 or newer and the `DATE` datatype (only `DATE` - **not** `DATETIME`!), then you can indeed also use the `YYYY-MM-DD` format and that will work, too, with any settings in your SQL Server.

Don't ask me why this whole topic is so tricky and somewhat confusing - that's just the way it is. But with the `YYYYMMDD` format, you should be fine for any version of SQL Server and for any language and dateformat setting in your SQL Server.

The recommendation for SQL Server 2008 and newer is to use `DATE` if you only need the date portion, and `DATETIME2(n)` when you need both date and time. You should try to start phasing out the `DATETIME` datatype if ever possible

Comment: `YYYYMMDD` is **not** an ISO format. The ISO format for just a date is `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes - theoretically, you're right - but `YYYY-MM-DD` is ***NOT*** language independent in SQL Server - just try it `SET LANGUAGE german
SELECT CAST('2015-05-25' AS DATETIME)` - this causes an **error**! But `SET LANGUAGE german
SELECT CAST('20150525' AS DATETIME)` works as expected (this applies **only** to the `DATETIME` datatype - with `DATE` or `DATETIME2(n)`, your ISO format works just fine)

Comment: @marc_s In my situation the input dateTime vary with system date format. Sometimes it may dd-mm-yyyyy , sometimes it may mm-dd-yyyy.

Comment: @marc_s Excuse me sir, is there any way we could contact you directly? My email address is available on my profile page. Thank you!